# SSAS calculated measure excluding nulls

Tags: null, ssas, average, measure

I have a fact-table like so:

Account#        |     Age

=============

1|10

2|20

3|NULL

I want to construct a calculated measure that gives me the average age when slicing through my datamodel.
When using: '[measure].Age/CountOfAccount#' I dont get the right average. It seems as if the NULL values of Age are seen as zero's and also get used in the calculation.
So in the above example ssas in my case does (10+20+0)/3 = 6.67 and this is wrong! In reality the average is: (10+20)/2 = 15

Could someone please help me out on how to construct the right SSAS calculated measure?

Thank you from Holland !

Comment: Look at `NonEmpty()` and `Non Empty()` MDX functions

Answer (score 0):

You can change the presentation values NULL as by selecting  each measure that you would like to retain the original NULL value.  Go to the properties menu (F4) and expand the Source property.  From there you want to change the NULLProcessing to Preserve.